# How to detect and Approve of Voting Buttons in Outlook VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to detect voting button and approve of it through VBA. I can select the Mail but I cant find any method in the MailItem Class to detect or Approve of the Voting Button.
My code for Selecting my Current Email

```
Dim myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer
Dim myOlSel As Outlook.Selection
Dim obj As MailItem
Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer
Set myOlSel = myOlExp.Selection
Set obj = myOlSel.Item(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it Using this Code:

```
Sub SendEmail()
Dim myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer
Dim hk() As String
Dim myOlSel As Outlook.Selection
Dim obj As MailItem
Dim obj2 As Outlook.MailItem
Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer
Set myOlSel = myOlExp.Selection
Set obj = myOlSel.Item(1)

For Each MA In obj.Actions
If MA.Name = "Approved" Then
Set obj2 = Ma.Execute
obj.Body = "My Message"
obj.Send
Exit For
End If
Next MA
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> I cant find any method in the MailItem Class to detect

The MailItem object has a `.VotingOptions` property (string) delimited by semicolon, e.g., "Approve;Reject", or "Yes;No", etc.

Any non-empty string should indicate the presence of voting buttons.

You indicate you want to "Approve of the Voting Button" -- what does this mean?   There are some standard response types, but there could also be a custom response(s).  You can't automatically handle *any potential set of responses*, and even if you know the set of responses, how do you "automatically" approve/reject or reply with yes/no -- unless you've *read and understand what they're asking you to vote on*?

So I think it is not a good approach, but here would be the method to use:

```
If TypeName(obj) = "MailItem" And obj.VotingOptions <> vbNullString Then
    obj.VotingResponse = "Yes"

End If
```

To check whether your "default" response is a valid response (invalid responses do not appear to raise errors when I test them):

```
Dim defaultResponse as String
Dim resp as String
defaultResponse = "Approve"

If TypeName(obj) = "MailItem" And obj.VotingOptions <> vbNullString Then
    For each resp in Split(obj.VotingOptions, ";")
        if resp = defaultResponse Then
           obj.VotingResponse = "Yes"
           Exit For
        End If
    Next
End If
```

You could of course expand on the logic to cover different scenarios,etc.

To "edit the response" you can do something like this:

```
Dim m As MailItem
Set m = obj.Reply  'or obj.ReplyAll
m.Body = "Insert your response here!" '## Modify as needed
m.Display 'optional
m.Save
m.Send
```

Comment: After you click on Approve button in main you get option of Editing it how can I also bring that option of editing it via VBA...I found the you can approve of vote by Action.Execute but how can make the Edit box to show

Comment: The answer I posted above addresses the two concerns you identified in your original question. If you have additional problems, I would encourage you to explore the Object model reference, and if you get stuck, ask Google first (probably someone else has already asked/answered very similar questions), and if you still are stuck, then just ask this as a **new** question :)  When you add follow-ups to Q's here, you're really limiting the audience who will *ever* see it to only me. When you ask a **new** question, everyone will see it and you will have a better chance of getting assistance.

Comment: Or, see the addition to my response. it should be pretty easy to "edit" a reply email.  If this solves the problem, do consider "Accepting" the answer.  Cheers.